# Cann't get file from classpath (using NIO2)

Tags: java, io, classpath, jelastic, nio2

I want to create a String from the content of the file. According [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/326440/1151381) I do it in this way:

```
private static String buildStringFromTemplate(String stringTemplatePath) throws IOException {
    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(stringTemplatePath));
    return new String(encoded, "UTF-8");
}
```

*(As I understand this is a path of new NIO2 API, that is a part of Java 7.)*

**stringTemplatePath** parameter is a name of the file (**"template.html"**). I check location of this file. It is in the classpath: **../classes/template.html**

After calling this function I get an exception:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: template.html
```

Maybe I send filename parameter to in a wrong way? I tried to send this modification: **"file:///template.html"** and **"classpath:template.html"**, but it didn't help.

Also I tried  this code:

```
private static String buildStringFromTemplate(String stringTemplatePath) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(stringTemplatePath);
    String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(absolutePath));
    return new String(encoded, "UTF-8");
}
```

I called this function I get following exception:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /opt/repo/versions/8.0.9/temp/template.html
```

So, file in classpath because **new File(stringTemplatePath)** can create a File. But this file has very strange path (**/opt/repo/versions/8.0.9/temp/template.html**). I use Jelastic as hosting (enviroment: Java 8, Tomcat 8), if it is metter.

---

**UPDATE: FINAL WORKING SOLUTION:**

```
private static String buildStringFromTemplate(String stringTemplatePath) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(stringTemplatePath);
    return IOUtils.toString(inputStream, "UTF-8"); 
}
```

*IOUtils* is util class from Apache IO Commons.

**Impotant note:**

If I just invoke *.getResourceAsStream(...)* from *class*, resource file will be not find and method will return **null**:

```
MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(stringTemplatePath);
```

So, I call *.getClassLoader()* before calling *.getResourceAsStream(...)* and it works perfectly:

```
MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(stringTemplatePath);
```

Comment: Don't use Path (or File; in 2015 don't use File at all) to access resources on the filesystem! There is `.getResourceAsStream()` for that

Comment: @fge Thx! With **.getResourceAsStream()** all works fine! Will you post your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be trying and accessing resources in your classpath as `Path`s.

While this will very probably work when your project sits in your IDE setup, it won't as soon as your project is packaged as a jar; it is then impossible to access them using even `Path` (and even though you can open zip files, therefore jars, as `FileSystem`s).

Use the dedicated methods to do that instead, starting with `.getResourceAsStream()`:

```
final InputStream in = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/resource");
```

Note that you will need to check whether the return code of that method is `null` (this is what is returned if the resource is not found in the classpath).

Comment: Unfortunately **MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(...);** doesn't work for me. In my case following code works: **MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(...);** Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If the file is really part of the classpath you should use:

`ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("/file name")`

this return InputStraem

 or 

`ClassName.class.getResource("/file name")`

this return URL